# Javascript and Remotipart - Why does single quotes vs double quotes matter?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload

So, I ran into a really interesting issue when playing around with uploading files remotely with [Remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart). I've tried the following two versions in my `update.js.erb` view, which the server sends after a successful file upload:

```
<%= remotipart_response do %>
    $("#container").html('<p>Success!</p><%= link_to('Back', gallery_items_path, :remote => true) %>');
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= remotipart_response do %>
    $("#container").html("<p>Success!</p><%= link_to('Back', gallery_items_path, :remote => true) %>");
<% end %>
```

Version one successfully changes the markup in `#container`, and version two fails without any error, server- or client-side. I thought single vs double quotes is only an issue when JSON is in play, but it seems I was wrong. I also noticed the [Remotipart example](https://github.com/JangoSteve/Rails-jQuery-Demo/blob/remotipart/app/views/comments/create.js.erb) uses single quotes exclusively, and I'm not sure if this is on purpose or not.

I'm using Rails 3.2.1, Remotipart 1.0.2, and (not sure if this matters) Chrome 17.

Does anyone know what causes this?

EDIT:
In answer to Alex's question:

In the first case, the output rendered is, as expected:

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Success!</p>
    <a href="/gallery_items" data-remote="true">Back</a>
</div>
```

In the second case, like I said, there was no change in the contents of `<div id="container">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual js passed to the browser in the 2nd case is;

```
$("#container").html("<p>Success!</p><a href="/gallery_items" data-remote="true">Back</a>");
```

The outer string is enclosed in `"` as its delimiter but as the contents also contain `"` it breaks. (`x = "aa"bb"` is invalid).

The former example uses the `'` delimiter so there is no problem.

To use `"` you must escape `link_to`'s return to produce

```
$("#container").html("<p>Success!</p><a href=\"/gallery_items\" data-remote=\"true\">Back</a>");
```

Answer (score 1):

link_to generates link-tag with double quotes, and it closes quotes in your javascript

Comment: Thanks for spotting this! Accepted Alex K's answer since it went into a bit more detail.